# Using Google voice number without data

Tags: sms, google-voice

So I know similar questions have been asked, but I feel my situation is a bit unique to everything I've read.  So I transferred my old number that everyone knows to Google voice, then I got a new phone with a new number that only has calling and texting.  I took the SIM card out of that phone and put it into my android phone, effectively giving me an android that has calling and texting, but no data plan.  I set up google voice to recognize my new number and call forward and everything seems to work while I'm on wifi, but I don't seem to receive text messages when I am not on wifi.

Is there a way to tell google voice to send all text messages it receives on my gv number to my carriers text plan with my new number (even if I don't have access to data)?  Also can replying to these messages without being near wifi show my gv number instead of my new phones number?  I can call Google voice and have it call the number I want to have my old number always show up, but with texting I haven't seemed to find a way yet.  Anyone in a similar situation have a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  If you navigate to [this](https://www.google.com/voice/#phones) page, and tick the *receive text messages on this phone* box all texts to Google voice will be forwarded to your phone via SMS.  This generates a new number for each of your contacts that will travel between Google voice before delivery, making it so you will always show as your Google voice number to friends, even if you are outside of wifi.  So just need to save the new number for each contact and be sure to text that instead of their actual number and it works perfect.  More info [here](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/117605?hl=en).